# Get column names from select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select in SQL Server like this:

```
Select name, email, username, tel 
from ViewName
```

I want to get a list of column names from that select.

**Note :**

**1.** I don't have table name

**2.** Select query is dynamic

Select query is in view

Comment: dont have a table name so how would u get result

Comment: I have just select in View and I don't have table name or tables name , may be View contains some table .

Comment: then just use Select name,email,username,tel from YOURVIEW

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma yes , updated

Comment: @PsarTak could you please rephrase `2. Select Query is Daynamic`

Comment: Do you want to get field names at runtime?

Comment: @DarkKnight I just can use SQl Server : Proceuer or function

Comment: if you want to get the list of columns of view then this will help: 
    `select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'my_view_name'`

Comment: I mean, do you want to get field names at runtime using a query in some stored procedure or function? or you want to just check schema in SSMS?

Comment: @DarkKnight yes Can get fields in function

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

> I hope this will work dynamically, it'll select all the `columns`
>   depending on the `Table_View_Name` you passed in the `parameter`.

```
declare @tab varchar(max)='Your_Dynamic_Table_View_Name'
declare @txt varchar(max)='SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name ='+@tab


declare @columns varchar(max)=(SELECT 
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + COLUMN_NAME
    FROM information_schema.columns where table_name=@tab
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
  ,1,2,'') AS NameValues)


exec('select '+@columns+' from '+@tab)
```

Comment: Query in View Is Onother Database in different server and I want Get Run thats view in my database  and just get fields name ,

Comment: I can't run thats view in my database because In my database does'nt exists that's table in that'view

Answer (score 0):

Try these..

```
sp_help 'viewName'
```

or

```
select c.* from syscolumns c inner join sysobjects o on o.id=c.id where o.name='viewName'
```